# GitHub Google Cloud Build - Multiple Repositories

Tags: github, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I'm interested in trying the [Google Cloud Build](https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build) continuous integration application on GitHub.

My application currently has 2 repositories I would like to deploy in a single Docker image. One of them is NodeJS API server, the other is a browser-based (no server side rendering) ReactJS application.

The idea would be to have the NodeJS repo serve requests under `/api/...` and any for any other URIs, it would serve up the React app.

My question, is it possible to have the Google Cloud Build grab another repo as well, as long as it's on GitHub? Ideally, a commit to either repo (in the right branch) would trigger the same underlying build. Just curios if this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be for GitHub Google Cloud to grab a *third* repository, which would be a "parent" repo referencing the right SHA1/branch of your two other repositories as **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

You can see an example of such a build in "[Static Website with Hugo, Cloudflare and Automated Builds using Google Cloud](https://www.tobias-schwarz.com/posts/8/)".
That would allow you to still work with "one" repository, even though that would check out two others in their own subfolders.